# Cucumber on groovy can't cast null to string when looks for step definition

Tags: java, groovy, junit, cucumber

I have some cucumber tests with step definitions written on groovy, and there is the following error when I run it:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: test.steps.StepDefs$_run_closure14.doCall() is applicable for argument types: (null, null, String, Integer, String) values: [null, null, qwer, 21, 1]
Possible solutions: doCall(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, short, java.lang.String), findAll(), findAll()
```

Scenario:

```
Scenario: justscenario
    Then ABC string qwer, short 21 version 1
```

Step definition:

```
Then(~'^ABC(?: ([^\\s]*))?(?: for "(\\S+)")? string ([^\\s]*), short (\\d+) version ([^\\s]*)$')
    { String key, String user, String stringId, short shortId, String version -> ...
```

In this case I don't need first two values so I omit it.
Why first two `nulls` weren't cast to `String`? `null` can be casted to any reference, isn't it?

Cucumber version is 4.8.0
Cucumber-groovy is 4.7.1
Junit is 4.12

Comment: `short` vs `Integer`?

Comment: @cfrick I can't believe I missed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to the use of `short` in the function to be called.

> ... test.steps.StepDefs$_run_closure14.doCall() is applicable for argument types: (null, null, String, **Integer**, String) values: [null, null, qwer, 21, 1]
>
> Possible solutions: doCall(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, **short**, java.lang.String), findAll(), findAll()